# How to convert string "{}" to empty dictionary {} JSON in Jolt? I am trying to replace "{}" by {} in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

Input JSON value :

```json
 {
  "age": [
    {
      "r": "r1",
      "d": "{}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired Output :

```json
{
  "age": [
    {
      "r": "r1",
      "d": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using **modify-overwrite-beta** but unable to replace string by empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following ***shift*** transformation spec in order to convert **`{}`** to **`null`**, and then ***modify*** transformation spec along with **`notNull`** function to return the desired result such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "age": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": { "@1": "&4[&3].&2" },
            "{}": "&3[&2].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "age": {
        "*": {
          "*": ["=notNull", {}]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[&1].&",
          "d": {
            "{}": "&3.[&2].&1.temp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "age": {
        "*": {
          "d": {
            "*": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```